# IBM Informix NodeJS Setup Issues - The INFORMIXSERVER value is not listed in the sqlhosts file or the Registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, macos, informix

I am attempting to connect **Informix** with **NodeJS** on **MacOS** but coming up against issues configuring the environment correctly.

In my ~/.bash_profile I have the following:

```
export INFORMIXDIR=/Applications/IBM/informix
export PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/bin:$PATH
export CSDK_HOME=/Applications/IBM/informix
export INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=/Users/username/Documents/sqlhosts

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli
```

As you can see, I have specified the `INFORMIXSQLHOSTS` variable to a local file rather than the default `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts` as I could not make sense of the multiple example files in that directory.

My local file for `sqlhosts` is as such:

```
#INFORMIXSERVER
informix_server     onsoctcp    localhost   my_alias
```

I am then running my node file `index.js`:

```
const opts = {
    database: 'db_name@informix_server',
    username: 'user',
    password: 'password'
};
const informix = require('informix')(opts)

informix.query('select name from table')
    .then(cursor => {
        return cursor.fetchAll({close: true});
    })
    .then(results => {
        console.log('results:', results);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

When I run this with `node index.js` I get the error:

> Error: [-25596] The INFORMIXSERVER value is not listed in the sqlhosts file or the Registry.

Can anybody help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you do a "dbaccess table_name@informix_server" from that same session?.  "table_name" is a strange name for a database. Also, If you are using the OpenInformix (IfxNode) it would be better if you open an issue in the project page rather than here.

Comment: @jsagrera Apologies, I changed `table_name` to `db_name`. I confused myself for a second. I'm not sure what you mean by the **dbaccess db_name@informix_server**. Also, I am using the "informix" npm lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/informix rather than IFX as I cannot locally build that one on my Mac.

Comment: dbaccess is a tool included in both the Informix server and the Informix CSDK (which you must already have installed in that box).
It can be used to do some admin task and to execute SQL statements. It should be in $INFORMIXDIR/bin, so it should be already in your PATH.  If you run "dbaccess db_name@informix_server" it will try to connect to your server/database in the same way that the Node.JS does.
It can be used to validate the SQLHOSTS information (e.g. file can be readed, comm info is valid)

Comment: @jsagrera I just saw a video where this is used! Shame it was in Spanish XD. I am trying to access my DB via the `dbaccess db@server` command but I am getting the error **25596: The INFORMIXSERVER value is not listed in the sqlhosts file or the Registry** again. The setup for my file structure is exactly like i have described up above.

Comment: @physicsboy Do you have an `INFORMIXSERVER` environment variable exported ?

Comment: @LuísMarques it turns out that you are required to have a "default" value for the INFORMIXSERVER in the environmental configs. It can be anything you like. It only comes into play if you are not specifying the server name when attempting to connect in the code. Usually we would write **`db_name@server_name`**, however if we omit the **`@server_name`** it will connect to the default defined within the environmental variables.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you are required to have a "default" value for the INFORMIXSERVER in the environmental configs. It can be anything you like. It only comes into play if you are not specifying the server name when attempting to connect in the code. Usually we would write db_name@server_name, however if we omit the @server_name it will connect to the default defined within the environmental variables.

For example:
In the environmental variables I define:

```
export INFORMIXSERVER=server_name
```

Then in the code I would connect to another server called `my_server` as such:

```
const opts = {
  database: 'my_db@my_server', // I specify the db name and the server name
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass'
}

const infx = require('Informix')(opts);
```

Whereas, if I were to omit the server name:

```
const opts = {
  database: 'my_db',
  ...
}
```

The code would interpret this as really being:

```
const opts = {
  database: 'my_db@server_name', // server name defined in INFORMIXSERVER
  ...
}
```